# RegEx matching odd number of characters at the beginning and the end of string

Tags: regex, codemirror

I have grammar is Lezer where I need to match a "custom string" which can start with any odd number of `"` and end with the same corresponding number. It can span multiple lines as well and anything inside needs to be `skipped` as far as the parser is concerned. I am struggling a little with the regEx part of the matching.

```
str"test"      // valid
str"""test""" // valid

str""test""     // not valid
str""""test"""" // not valid
```

I am trying to match the beginning and end of that string.

I tried among other things `"("")*[^"]` but it matches the first letter after the odd double quotes (due to the `[^"]` which is something I would like to avoid.

For matching the end I have a similar issue.

So with the given input of:

```
1 str"test"
2 str"""
3 a
4 b
5 c
6 """
7 str""nope""
```

I am trying to match only `str"` for line 1 and `str"""` for line 2 and not match on line 7.

Need to match the ends as well (not in the same regex). So the match should be on `"` for line 1 and `"""` for line 6.

I have this so far: **start**: `^str"("")*[^"]` **end**: `[^"]"("")*$` but it is not optimal.

FYI I need start and end since the expectation is when you start writing and we hit a match on the beginning the highlighting in the editor should highlight all remaining text as a string until you have a matching odd number of `"`.

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps like this https://regex101.com/r/dZ4l1L/1 `(?<!")("(?:"")*)(?!")[^]*?(?<!")\1(?!")`

Comment: I think as far as regex is concerned just `(?<!")("(?:"")*)(?!")` would get me going. Unfortunately in this scenario, I can not find a way to utilize Negative Lookbehind with Lezer. Will look more into it. Thanks again!

Comment: There is a match alternative for the lookbehind `(?:^|[^"])("(?:"")*)(?!")` https://regex101.com/r/WVsd0x/1 but that either asserts the start of the string, or matches any character except a double quote.